# Prove that $(x+y+z)^n=x^n+y^n+z^n$ where $n$ is an odd positive integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,y,z\in R$ and $(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3$.Prove that $(x+y+z)^n=x^n+y^n+z^n$ where $n$ is an odd positive integer.

I tried to solve it.But did not reach till last step.

$(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3$
$\Rightarrow (x+y+z)^3-x^3=y^3+z^3$
I simplified this and get $x+y+z=\frac{-3yz}{x}$

What should i do now?Please guide me.

Comment: Am I overlooking something or is the part that has to be proven the same as the assumption, if $n=3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)^3-x^3$$

$$\iff(y+z)(y^2-yz+z^2)=(y+z)\{(x+y+z)^2+(x+y+z)x+x^2\}$$

On simplification we have $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=0$

Comment: I understood till here,but still not able to finish the question.@lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @diya, Now the product of the three terms is zero. What can we conclude from it?

Comment: Yes i understood.Thanks.